# Code not working and I don't understand why

Tags: c#

I've been writing this code for my programming class and for some reason it won't work. I'm still new to coding so I don't understand what's wrong.

It's a program where you input the soda-bottles you want in a soda crate. Then you can ask it to print out what you have in the crate and how much it will cost in total.

I know you're not supposed to paste your whole code but I'm at a loss to what is wrong.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System;

namespace sodacrate
{
    class Flaska
    {
        private string namn
        private int pris

        public Flaska(string _namn, int _pris);
        {
            namn = _namn;
            pris = _pris;
        }
        public string Namn
        {
            get
            {
                return namn;
            }
            set
            {
                namn = value;
            }
        }
        public int Pris
        {
            get
            {
                return pris;
            }
            set
            {
                pris = value;
            }
        }

    }





    class Sodacrate
    {
        private Flaska[] flaskor = 0;
        private int antal_flaskor = 0; //Håller reda på antal flaskor

        public Sodacrate()
        {
            flaskor = new Flaska[24];
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Välkommen till detta läskbacksprogramm."); //Text som välkommnar användaren

            int input = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Välj ett alternativ som du vill ska utföras:");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Lägg till flaskor till läskbacken");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Se vilka flaskor som finns i läskbacken");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Räkna ut totalpriset för läskbacken");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Stäng av program");

                input = int.Parse(Console.WriteLine()); //Tar emot input och omvandlar till en integer

                switch (input)
                {
                        case 1: add_soda();
                        case 2: print_crate();
                        case 3: calc_total();
                        case 4: Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas");
                        default: Console.WriteLine("Fel inmatning. Var vänlig och välj bland alternativ ovanför.");
                        break;
                }


            } while (input != 0);




        }

        public void add_soda()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Välj dryck att lägga till i läskbacken:");


            Console.WriteLine("1. Fanta, 10 kr");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Coca-Cola, 15 kr");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Sprite, 9 kr");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Mountain Dew, 17 kr");


            int input = 0; //Skapa variabel för att ta emot input

            for (int i = 0; i < flaskor.Length; i++)
            {
                while (!int.TryParse(Cosole.ReadLine(), out input) || !(input <= 4 && input >= 1))  //Ser till att man bara kan skriva in vad programmet frågar efter.
                {
                    "Fel inmatning. Var vänlig och välj bland alternativ ovanför.";
                }
                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Fanta.");
                        flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new flaskor("Fanta", 10);
                        antal_flaskor++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Coca-Cola.");
                        flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new flaskor("Coca-Cola", 15);
                        antal_flaskor++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Sprite.");
                        flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new flaskor("Sprite", 9);
                        antal_flaskor++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Du valde Mountain Dew.");
                        flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new flaskor("Mountain Dew", 17);
                        antal_flaskor++;
                        break;
                    default: Console.WriteLine("Fel inmatning. Var vänlig och välj bland alternativ ovanför.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void print_crate()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < flaskor.Length; i++)
            {
                if (flaskor[i] != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}. Namn: {1}, Pris: {2}", i, flaskor[i].Namn, flaskor[i].Pris);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tom plats.");
                }
            }
        }

        public int calc_total()
        {
            int summa = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < antal_flaskor, i++)
            {
                summa += flaskor[i].Pris;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Det totala priset blir {0} kr.");
        }


    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Skapar ett objekt av klassen Sodacrate som heter sodacrate
             Sodacrate Läskback = new Sodacrate();

            var sodacrate = new Sodacrate();

            sodacrate.Run();
            Läskback.print_crate();
            Läskback.calc_total();
            Läskback.add_soda();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why don't you help us helping you by explaining to us how your program is wrong. Just telling us that "something is wrong" is telling us nothing. Are there any errors? Is your program behaving in a way you don't expect -- how does it behave, and how would you expect it to behave? etc...

Comment: I see at least one compiler error. Always include full error message(s) when asking here. Make sure we know about which line it is etc.

Comment: As a side note, if you don't understand what your program is doing and **why** it is doing what it does (assuming it compiles and runs at least), spend some time learning about the awesome [step debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger) I hope your programming class will (sooner or later) spend some lessons/hours on how to do basic debugging. You see, a debugger is for a programmer what a stethoscope is for a doctor; a doctor is not a doctor unless he knows how to use a stethoscope ;-)

Comment: I have copy and pasted you code in visual studio and their are lots of errors such as curly braces in the wrong place and semi colons in the wrong place. I will put an answer of the code corrected.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

See below the corrected code. I went in visual studio and corrected it for you and it works. You was not far off. Just a few colons and curly braces were in the wrong place and so it would not build. Code below:

```
using System;

namespace sodacrate
{
public class Flaska
{
    private string namn;
    private int pris;

    public Flaska(string _namn, int _pris)
    {
        namn = _namn;
        pris = _pris;
    }

    public string Namn
    {
        get { return namn; }
        set { namn = value; }
    }

    public int Pris
    {
        get { return pris; }
        set { pris = value; }
    }
}

class Sodacrate
{
    private Flaska[] flaskor;
    private int antal_flaskor = 0; //Håller reda på antal flaskor

    public Sodacrate()
    {
        flaskor = new Flaska[24];
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Välkommen till detta läskbacksprogramm."); //Text som välkommnar användaren

        int input = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Välj ett alternativ som du vill ska utföras:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Lägg till flaskor till läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Se vilka flaskor som finns i läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Räkna ut totalpriset för läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Stäng av program");

            input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Tar emot input och omvandlar till en integer

            switch (input)
            {
                case 1:
                    add_soda();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    print_crate();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    calc_total();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Fel inmatning. Var vänlig och välj bland alternativ ovanför.");
                    break;
            }


        } while (input != 0);




    }

    public void add_soda()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Välj dryck att lägga till i läskbacken:");


        Console.WriteLine("1. Fanta, 10 kr");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Coca-Cola, 15 kr");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Sprite, 9 kr");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Mountain Dew, 17 kr");


        int input = 0; //Skapa variabel för att ta emot input

        for (int i = 0; i < flaskor.Length; i++)
        {
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) || !(input <= 4 && input >= 1))  //Ser till att man bara kan skriva in vad programmet frågar efter.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fel inmatning. Var vänlig och välj bland alternativ ovanför.");

            }
            switch (input)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Fanta.");
                    flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new Flaska("Fanta", 10);
                    antal_flaskor++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Coca-Cola.");
                    flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new Flaska("Coca-Cola", 15);
                    antal_flaskor++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Sprite.");
                    flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new Flaska("Sprite", 9);
                    antal_flaskor++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Du valde Mountain Dew.");
                    flaskor[antal_flaskor] = new Flaska("Mountain Dew", 17);
                    antal_flaskor++;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Fel inmatning. Var vänlig och välj bland alternativ ovanför.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void print_crate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < flaskor.Length; i++)
        {
            if (flaskor[i] != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}. Namn: {1}, Pris: {2}", i, flaskor[i].Namn, flaskor[i].Pris);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tom plats.");
            }
        }
    }

    public int calc_total()
    {
        int summa = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < antal_flaskor; i++)
        {
            summa += flaskor[i].Pris;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Det totala priset blir {summa} kr.");

        return summa;
    }


}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Skapar ett objekt av klassen Sodacrate som heter sodacrate
        Sodacrate Läskback = new Sodacrate();

        var sodacrate = new Sodacrate();

        sodacrate.Run();
        Läskback.print_crate();
        Läskback.calc_total();
        Läskback.add_soda();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
}
```